# iMacros website form dropdown menu

Tags: scripting, imacros

I'm trying to automate filling a form that reads data from a csv file and inputs the data into the website form in the screenshot below. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the gender dropdown selection to work correctly.

Screenshot of website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZLP3.png

Options for gender dropdown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWr79.png

I am using:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:new_patient ATTR=NAME:gender CONTENT=${{!COL5}}

Where my csv file has the letter "F" (for female) in Column 5. I have tried using % as well. I am currently using the iMacros 10 browser but will ultimately use Chrome as my browser of choice if possible for this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code will work:

```
SET option EVAL("switch ('{{!COL5}}') {case 'M': s = 'Male'; break; case 'F': s = 'Female'; break; case 'U': s = 'Undifferentiated'; break; default: '';}")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:new_patient ATTR=NAME:gender CONTENT=${{option}}
```

...or just so:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:new_patient ATTR=NAME:gender CONTENT=${{!COL5}}*
```

Comment: Thanks @Shugar. But I'm still having issues. The first code gives the following error: 

Error -1250: JScript statement in EVAL contains the following error: Variable 's' has not been declared. Line 12: SET option EVAL("switch ('{{!COL5}}') {case 'M': s = 'Male'; break; case 'F': s = 'Female'; break; case 'U': s = 'Undifferentiated'; break; default: '';}")

While the second example always chooses Male which is the same issue I was getting previously.  

Can you clear up how to declare the s variable or have any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Both codes were tested with Firefox and the first one with Chrome as well: no errors occurred. Take a look at several suggestions. As to the 1st – write down the code like this `SET option EVAL("var s; switch ('{{!COL5}}') {case 'M': s = 'Male'; break; case 'F': s = 'Female'; break; case 'U': s = 'Undifferentiated'; break; default: '';}")`. As to the 2nd – try the following codes `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:new_patient ATTR=NAME:gender CONTENT=$F*`, `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:new_patient ATTR=NAME:gender CONTENT=$M*` etc. and pay attention to the results. They must be as expected.